# Modern SharePoint Calendar List: How to edit "All Day Event" field in 'Quick Edit' view and/or set default to True

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calendar, events, modern

We migrated a calendar list from SharePoint 2010 to modern online SharePoint. In older SharePoint we could do in-line editing or Data Sheet View editing in the "All Day Event" calendar field. During the migration process the 'yes/no' entries for this field were not copied over.

In modern SharePoint, the 'All Day Event' field is visible, but not editable the same way. Each item can be opened individually in edit form and checkbox for this field can be checked but that's not a feasible solution for hundreds of line items. Even to add new items, users prefer to copy multiple Excel rows and paste to the SharePoint list and 'All Day Event' field remains blank.

Need help to determine how to enable this field to accept values in Quick Edit view or at least have 'All Day Event' set to True as default. This field shows in modify view window but not under 'Columns' in list settings for us to edit default entry.

Reading another post, I checked to ensure that Event management is turned on, and Event is already a default content type for this list. Scripting is not a good option as we may not be allowed to use it.

Comment: You can try Power Automate to set this field value to true. Check this video at this specific time: https://youtu.be/VqvloXh68Mw?t=230

Comment: Are you using [SharePoint Online modern list calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)? What is the column/data type of All Day Event column?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to set it to `true` by default at list level. You can try changing it at site column level. Note: It will change the default selection for all lists using event content type in this SharePoint site.

Comment: @PradipR., Power Automate is our backup option but in case of SharePoint owners changing and people moving, the flow will need to be restarted by someone every few years.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I'm guessing the datatype is Boolean since it was a 'yes/no' field in old SharePoint and now is a 'checkbox' field (in edit form view).

Comment: @GaneshSanap tried to look for ways to change column default as True for "All Day Event" at site level but that column is not editable. When try to get to open it, there's no default option there, only which group to add it to, and even that seems fixed because I tried moving it to Core contacts and calendar group but it doesn't show in that group.